# Answer wrongly flagged as comment then deleted

Tags: discussion

[RGB control via website](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48673/rgb-control-via-website)

The answer is correct, and was deleted. Aside from the english-as-a-second-language grammatical errors, there is no reason to delete it. Just adds more fuel to the newbie-hate here.

Edit: The answer was not redundant. Unlike the other answer which vaguely references SPI then provides a **link without any context**, the deleted answer **EXPLICITLY** states which pins the Ethernet Shield uses, which answers the question properly.

Comment: That question is way too old to migrate to Arduino.SE .  Bummer.

Answer (score 1):

As is being discussed [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3744/11683), new but redundant answers to old questions do not add value to the site.

While Matt Johnson's comment saying that it was "not an answer" was incorrect, we generally delete such answers and then protect the question.

Comment: But link only answers do?

Comment: And why do we have badges that encourage answering and editing old questions?

Comment: Why not lock questions older than 3 months then?

Comment: We have the badges to encourage improving questions and adding new material in answers. Locking would prevent that from happening. Redundant answers by newbies don't accomplish either of those things.

Comment: It may have been a better candidate for converting into a comment, since it did add new information.

Comment: I thought comments could disappear

Comment: @W5VO  Done.  Converted that deleted answer into a comment.  (Before I got the diamond, I sometimes flagged deleted questions in old threads for conversion into comments.)